# App to slice'n'dice video, specifically remove chunks, on a Mac?

Tags: macos, video, software-rec, editing

I have a couple of collections of DVD Box-Sets I've ripped to my mac. Now I'd like to sweeten the viewing experience by removing the title sequences and credits so that viewing doesn't mean I have to keep reaching for the remote to skip 30 seconds of annoying music (think watching multiple episodes of Family Guy).

If I can find an app that will let me do this reasonably quickly manually that would be great, but it would be perfect if I could dump a load of commands into a file and have everything trimmed while the mac is "inactive". I'm thinking that if I can specify chunks of time to remove from the original file that would be perfect.

I had a quick look at importing into iMovie to do it manually and gave up at the "Processing Thumbnails" stage as it said it would be a couple of hours to produce them for a 45min mp4 file, which I can understand at 25fps but I'm not willing to wait, especially when I've got over a week's worth of files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a bit more than Quicktime provides, iMovie (part of the iLife suite) should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

For one offs, QuickTime Player should suffice. In QuickTime Player (so long as you have Pro with Leopard or earlier, or just regular QuickTime Player in Snow Leopard) you can trim the video and remove the 30 seconds.

Comment: Its possible to trim the end or the beginning, but not any chunk from the middle of the video.

Comment: In QuickTime Player 7 (if you have QuickTime Pro) you can - unfortunately the new "trim" feature in QuickTime Player for Snow Leopard does not.

Answer (score 0):

VLC media player can slice video by adding a start and end point bookmark, then exporting. Its all in the bookmarks window.